# Outlook Task REST API - Not authorized 401

Tags: rest, api, powershell, outlook

I am trying to access the Outlook Rest API 2.0 from Powershell to view and create tasks. I created an application and am successfully retrieving the access_token and the required scope (Tasks.ReadWrite). See my response:

```
token_type     : Bearer
scope          : openid Tasks.ReadWrite
expires_in     : 3600
ext_expires_in : 3600
access_token  :   token_value
id_token  :  id_token_value
```

Hoever when trying to get a list of tasks i am getting a 401 response (not authorized). See the powershell code below:

```
$header = @{"Bearer" = "$($response.access_token)"}
$task_list = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Header $Header -Uri" https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/tasks"
```

The exception is the following:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : the remote server returned an error (401) unauthorized
+ $task_list = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Header $Header -Uri "https ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMetho 
   d], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCo 
   mmand
```

Comment: What did you check? Besides the incorrect Authentication header (which TToni pointed you to) I don't see other stuff you tried. Are the permissions correct in AzureAD for this application?

Answer (score 1):

This is not the correct method to transmit a bearer token in the header. I'm no expert on the matter, but [RFC 6750](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750) says you should transmit it with an `Authorization` header with the `Bearer` method, like this:

```
$header = @{"Authorization" = "Bearer $($response.access_token)"}
```

Comment: I am getting the exact same respone by using this header